# Is Norwegian language supported?

Tags: dual-boot, package-management, keyboard-layout, language-support

Can I get Norwegian language support in Ubuntu? I don't want to get an operating system that doesn't support my language. I also wonder if I can type in Norwegian, can I do that?

Can I install Ubuntu on a computer which already runs Windows? When I download items from the internet, must I choose the Linux version or is there anything else that I should check before I download packages from the internet for installation in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu installer allows you to choose from several different languages, Norwegian is one of them. The same goes for keyboard layouts, so typing with Norwegian keys is no problem either.

The installer will also offer to install Ubuntu in addition to any existing OS like your Windows.

As for your last question, Ubuntu comes with a package management system, so you most likely won't have to download any programs manually. Instead, you can just tell the Software Center (or any other package management tool of your choice) to do the downloading and installing for you.

Comment: thanks for you help! i didn't take long time. your answer really helped me. maybe i choose ubuntu. thank you! :-)